# Can a Force user ignore a negative Combined Force Power Check?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

On one session a player with a Force Sensitive character tried to use the Move Force Power to make a ranged (discipline) attack check against an enemy with adversary 3 talent.

This PC rolled 2 despairs,  3 black pips on his 2 force dice, and 3 success.

Nevertheless he declared that he didn't wanted to use the Dark Side Pips, so no Force Points were generated. I didn't know how to rule that so I made a pause to check the rules in the Force chapter in the Force and Destiny book:

- A Force Check **is always "succesfully" activated**, even if no Force
  Points were generated.
- The entire check is **made at one time** on a Combined Force Power
  Check
- The character should generate and spend Force Points **after rolling 
  the dice pool, before interpreting the results** of the rest of the pool.

This made me realize than a player can roll the whole Combined Force Check, take a look at the overall result, realize that is an utter catastrophe and declare that he don't want to generate Force Points.

***Should we interpret the result of the check (advantages, despair, etc.) at this point? Or ignore the result because he didn't want to generate force points?***

This also presents another problem, a player will only generate Force Points with Dark side pips if the check is an overall success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure where you found "A Force Check is always "succesfully" activated, even if no Force Points were generated." but in Force and Destiny page 298/299 it says under the control upgrade for the move talent that allows attacks:

> [The attack] only succeeds if the user can also spend enough [force
>   pips] to move the object.

And to answer your question I am not sure on what basis you would ignore the result rather than interpreting it. A check was made, you interpret the results.  The fact that the user failed to activate the force power successfully shouldn't make a difference to this. So they suffer from the effects of the two despairs and fail to hit their target with the attack.

As for how to interpret the result perhaps the force user succeeded in moving the object but in a way that advantaged the enemy (eg provided cover), perhaps the force user is so distracted by his attempts that he loses track of the battle. The exact interpretation of the results is of course a bit too subjective to dwell on. :)

Comment: Regarding the Force Check is always "successfully" activated: I read it at page 280, the last paragraph of the FORCE POWER CHECKS, just before Combined Force Power Checks

Comment: Reading through that section I see under combined checks it also says "Unless specifically stated otherwise, the character must generate enough [force points] to activate the Force talent or Force power's basic power (or appropriate control upgrades) and must generate at least one uncancelled [success] for the check to succeed" so I suspect that part you quoted only applies to standard force power checks, not combined checks.